# A protocol is not conforming to a class inherited from a generic parent class?

Tags: swift, generics, protocols, standards-compliance

I am trying to conform a class to a protocol however, I am getting error. Here is the code:

```
class UserSearchViewController: GenericSearchViewController<User>
```

I am trying to conform it to a `buttontappeddelegate`:

```
extension UserSearchViewController: ButtonDidGetTappedDelegate {
func button(wasTappedInCell cell: UserCollectionViewCell) {
    print("Cell Tapped")
   }
}
```

I get the error when I assign self to the delegate:

```
adapter.delegate = self
```

> Cannot assign value of type 'UserSearchViewController.Type' to type 'ButtonDidGetTappedDelegate?'

What is the issue here? Any help would be appreciated.

```
class UserSearchViewController: GenericSearchViewController<User> {
    static func searchV (Config: ConfigurationProtocol,
                     dataSource: DataSource,
                     viewer: User) ->  UserSearchViewController
  let vc = UserSearchViewController(Config, dataSource,viewer) 
   ......
   ...
  adapter.delegate = self
  return vc

}
```

Comment: Where are you writing the line `adapter.delegate = self`? Can you show the surrounding code? The error message makes me suspect that you are writing that line in a static context.

Comment: @Sweeper The line is in a static function. That static function returns the view controller of type UserSearchViewController. I will update the code.

Comment: Also, you seem to be extending `ChatUserSearchViewController`, but you said you wanted to make `UserSearchViewController` (without `Chat`) conform to the protocol.

Comment: @Sweeper Just updated the code

Comment: @juliand665 Corrected it! Thats not an issue.

Comment: It was probably part of the issue. Combined with Sweeper's answer, that should do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are doing this in a static function, you can't use `self` to refer to an instance of your VC. Instead, you have an instance of your VC already! It's `vc`.

Just set `vc` as the delegate instead of `self`:

```
adapter.delegate = vc
```

Comment: To clarify, being in a static context means that you're not within any specific instance of your class (in this case, you're only just creating such an instance). This means that `self` refers to the _type_ `UserSearchViewController` as a whole, rather than an _instance_ of it, but only instances of types can conform to protocols.

Comment: @juliand665 If I want to use the instance of the class elsewhere within a class, is that possible? For example I create a variable of type UserSearchViewController? within the class. Is it possible to assign vc to that variable?

Comment: Yes. That's exactly where you'd use `self`—in a non-static context (i.e. whenever the function doesn't have the word `static` on it), `self` refers to the instance you're currently "in", rather than the type itself.

Comment: If you're still in a static context, you can of course access it like `vc.myVariable = vc`